# Refresh WPF MVVM Datagrid when windows closes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I saw a few responses on SE for this kind of question but nothing that seems to have fully been answered.

I have a Window which has a datagrid (frmOpenOrders.tblOpenOrders).

The windows lists all open orders on the program.

I believe I have bound it correctly, but this is my first WPF MVVM project ever.

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tblOpenOrders"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                  IsReadOnly="true" RowHeaderWidth="0"    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
```

**CS:**

```
private BindableCollection<ViewModel.openOrder> CurrentOpenOrders { get; set; }
private void loadData()
        {
            
            string sqlString = @"SELECT tblOrder.orderID, firstName, lastName, tblOrder.itemName, tblOrder.itemQuantity, tblStaff.StaffName AS orderedBy, Format([createdDate],""hh:nn am/pm"") AS orderTime, Format([createdDate],""dd mmm"") AS orderDate
                                    FROM tblStaff INNER JOIN tblOrder ON tblStaff.staffID = tblOrder.createdBy WHERE orderedBy is null";


            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cstring.con))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter fillDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, cstring.con))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("tableData");
                    fillDA.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();



                    CurrentOpenOrders = new BindableCollection<ViewModel.openOrder>();

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        CurrentOpenOrders.Add(new ViewModel.openOrder
                        {
                            orderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["orderID"].ToString()),
                            firstName = dr["firstName"].ToString(),
                            lastName = dr["lastName"].ToString(),
                            orderedBy = dr["orderedBy"].ToString(),
                            itemName = dr["itemName"].ToString(),
                            itemQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(dr["itemQuantity"].ToString()),
                            orderedTime =dr["orderTime"].ToString(),
                            orderedDate = dr["orderDate"].ToString()

                        });
                        
                        
                    }
                    tblOpenOrders.DataContext = CurrentOpenOrders;
                }
            }
        }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
    {

        public class openOrder
        {
            public int orderID { get; set; }
            public string orderedDate { get; set; }
            public string orderedTime { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string itemName { get; set; }
            public int itemQuantity { get; set; }
            public string orderedBy { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

It seems to be working correctly but I'm happy for advice on errors in it.

Now on the Datagrid I have a button to open a child window for the record of that row (frmProcessOrder)
This is also working fine.

What I need is for the datagrid on Window1 **(tblOpenOrders)** to update when I close the child.
Pretty much the (frmProcessOrder) closes and this should remove that record from the datagrid as this order has been processed.

My understanding is that I need to update the bindable collection...?

My other option is just closing frmOpenOrders when i open the child, then when the child opens I will reopen the frmOpenOrders which will thus be ok and updated.

Thanks for any advice, I just couldn't quite figure this one out.

Gangel

Comment: You've got a reference to ui in loaddats. That's not mvvm. You should have a separate viewmodel class. That implements inotifypropertychanged. If you're replacing a bound collection then that should raise propertychanged in it's setter. That viewmodel should work if instantiated with no view. The viewmodel instance should be datacontext of the view. The itemssource of the datagrid should bind to the property from the viewmodel exposes the collection.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, obviously my skills aren't up to this yet as that pretty much went over my head.  I'll study more on this and try to get this MVVM stuff going first.